# Error metodo debe retornar un tipo c#

Tags: c#

Hola tengo un problema y esque siempre me muestra el mismo mensaje que debe retornar un tipo lo que hago es lo siguiente:
Error metodo debe retornar un tipo:

```
var a = AssemblyHome(data);
```

El codigo de mi funcion es:

```
internal static AssemblyHome(byte[] data)
        {
            Assembly asmLoad = Assembly.Load(data);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[data.LongLength];


                SYSTEM_INFO pSI = new SYSTEM_INFO();
                GetSystemInfo(ref pSI);
                uint i = 0;

                IntPtr hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_TERMINATE, 0, GetCurrentProcessId());

                if (hProcess == IntPtr.Zero)
                    return asmLoad;

                while (i < pSI.lpMaximumApplicationAddress)
                    if (VirtualQueryEx(hProcess, i, out memBasicInfo, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(memBasicInfo)))
                    {
                        if (memBasicInfo.Protect == MemoryProtection.ReadWrite && memBasicInfo.State == MemoryState.Commit && memBasicInfo.Type == MemoryType.Mapped)
                        {
                            if (ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, memBasicInfo.BaseAddress, buffer, buffer.Length, 0))
                            {
                                if (ByteArrayCompare(buffer, data))
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine(memBasicInfo.BaseAddress);
                                    WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, memBasicInfo.BaseAddress, new byte[] { 0, 0 }, 2, 0);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        i = (uint)memBasicInfo.BaseAddress + (uint)memBasicInfo.RegionSize;
                    }

            return asmLoad;
        }
```

Devuelvo el ensamblado pero siempre me devuelve el mismo error.

Answer (score 2):

Tal como el error te dice, no has incluído en su definición el tipo que devolverá la función. En este caso, parece que quieres devolver una instancia de tipo `Assembly`, así que la función la debes definir así:

```
// Nota que se le agrega "Assembly"
internal static Assembly AssemblyHome(byte[] data)
```